# How to find drag of a cylinder?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, aerodynamics, flow, viscosity

How can I find a drag on the cylinder placed in uniform water flow, if I know a velocity field around it? [image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow_around_a_circular_cylinder

Comment: Is this turbulent flow or laminar flow?

Comment: I don't know what is the proper classification, but NASA gives an option for Unsteady-Oscillating

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a potential flow, the resistance is zero (d'Alembert paradox). In the case of viscous flow, it is necessary to calculate the pressure distribution and the derivative of velocity along the normal. Calculate the integral
$$F_D=\int _S{\left( \mu \frac {\partial u_t}{\partial n}n_y-pn_x\right)\mathrm dS}$$
The drag coeﬃcient is $c_D=\frac {2F_D}{\rho U_0^2D}$. Here
$\mu$ is viscosity coefficient, $\vec n=(n_x,n_y)$ - normal vector, $D$ - diameter.
The algorithm for solving the problem in the case of a laminar flow with the formation of Karman vortices, see on [Solver for unsteady flow with the use of Mathematica FEM](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064) . Figure $1$ shows the velocity distribution at $Re=100$, the drag and lift coeﬃcients, and  the pressure diﬀerence $\Delta P$  is deﬁned, with the front and end point of the cylinder.
[image: fig1]
Experimental data of the velocity distribution around the cylinder at $Re=4216.8$  @Anton Kovalyov
[image: fig2]

Comment: Oh, I see, is it from the stress constitutive equation? I heard of the momentum method, that is related to the momentum deficit of flow behind the cylinder in the wake region. I just dont understand how far from the cylinder should I compute the integral?

Comment: Do you assume that the flow is turbulent?

Comment: Tbh, I don't really know, I looked it up on NASA and it seems to be Unsteady- Oscillating. My Re = 4200 . And it does look like the picture you sent

Comment: I am writing code for this case now. Formulate the problem more accurately and give a link to the NASA page.

Comment: I can give you an access to a data set I have from the experiment https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ierNNqSBYLoluDeC8_mJLUsHQR5Xkwo9a-qot97Xq8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: And here is NASA web pagehttps://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/dragsphere.html, I also added a picture of the velocity field from PIV

Comment: Your data obtained in a wind tunnel?

Comment: No no, it is from the water channel.

Comment: Where is the center of the cylinder in the coordinates $(x,y)$ and what is the diameter of the cylinder? Where does the flow come from?

Comment: D = 42 mm, C(20,0). I think you can see it in the picture above, but the stream is from left to right and the average velocity = 0.1 m/s

Comment: @AntonKovalyov I have processed your data - see the update. But to calculate the $c_D$, you need to know the pressure distribution on the surface. How fast is the data received? Is it an instant field metering or time average?

Comment: It was time averaged. The flow was filmed for 3 seconds